# My PeriodFormatter is not behaving as I expect - what have I done wrong?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm having trouble using Joda Time's PeriodFormatter.  I want one to report days, hours, minutes and seconds but my attempt seems to be wrapping around weeks.  What should I be doing differently?

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

public class Problems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendDays()
            .appendSuffix(" day", " days")
            .appendSeparator(", ")
            .appendHours()
            .appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
            .appendSeparator(", ")
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
            .appendSeparator(", ")
            .appendSeconds()
            .appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
            .toFormatter();

        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        DateTime justUnderAWeekAgo = now.minusDays(7).plusMinutes(1);
        DateTime justOverAWeekAgo = now.minusDays(7).minusMinutes(1);
        System.out.println(now);
        System.out.println(justUnderAWeekAgo);
        System.out.println(justOverAWeekAgo);
        // I am happy with the following:
        System.out.println(
            formatter.print(new Period(justUnderAWeekAgo, now)));
        // But not with this (outputs "1 minute" but I want "7 days, 1 minute"):
        System.out.println(
            formatter.print(new Period(justOverAWeekAgo, now)));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I guess I can see why this isn't working - i.e. that the formatter just prints the Period's various values, and since Periods store a value for weeks, the value for days on my problem period is indeed 0.  But I still need a good way of doing this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you do not ask your `PeriodFormatter` to display the weeks.

Two possibilities:

**Solution 1:** Display the weeks:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroNever()
        .appendWeeks()
        .appendSuffix(" week", " weeks")
        .appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix(" day", " days")
        .appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
        .appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
        .appendSeparator(", ")
        .appendSeconds()
        .appendSuffix(" second", " seconds")
        .toFormatter();
```

The second output in your example will be:

```
1 week, 1 minute
```

Solution 2: Display only the days so you will have to use the `PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime()`:

```
new Period(justUndeAWeekAgo, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

Using this second solution, you can keep your `PeriodFormatter` as it is now. The second output in your example will then be:

```
7 days, 1 minute
```

Comment: You were missing a separator for the weeks - added.